# Find each topic which has a comment from user XXX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

As the title states, I would like to know, before writing a join, if there is a way to write this query in rails.

I need to find every topic which has one post from user XXX.
What are the approach that is considered "correct" for this type of query in rails?

**Edit 1:**

My models are these actually:

- Topic has_many Comment
- Comment belongs_to User
- Comment belongs_to Topic
- User has_many Comment
- User has_many Topic

Comment: We know nothing about your models, hard to tell. Also, `joins` can be expressed using Rails syntax, take a look at the official  Activerecord doc : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Sorry! I were updating the question because I forgot models, now you can read them. Thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto: Every time I read rails guides, I'm surprised how powerful this framework is!

Comment: It's meant to be easy to use, but you have to learn its conventions to make it easy and (almost) magic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Topic.joins(:comments).where('comments.user_id = ?', user.id).uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

From the top of my head if you want to match the user's name:

```
Topic.joins(:comments => :user).where("users.name" => "xxx")
```